# Replace SVG innertext value with a href link

Tags: c#, xml, linq, svg, linq-to-xml

I am working with SVG file, that are same of XML.
I need to replace InnerText of some elements with a href new element with its InnerText

An example of my element is

```
<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" fill="#ff0000" stroke-width="0" x="239.61" y="74.89" font-size="3.37" opacity="1.00" font-family="Arial Narrow">3070119100</text>
```

I need to replace 3070119100 InnerText to

```
<a link:href="http://www.google.it">3070119100</a>
```

I suppose I need to add a child  with as InnerText the previous value.

I would like to work with LINQ XDocument but is appreciate also code with XMLDocument.

WHAT I AM ABLE TO DO:
I was able working with XMLDocument to add child but not to clear innerText text element:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(_SVG);
    XmlNodeList elementListText = doc.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    for (int i = 0; i < elementListText.Count; i++)
    {
        XmlElement a = doc.CreateElement("a");
        a.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
        a.SetAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
        a.SetAttribute("xlink:href", "http://www.google.it");
        a.InnerText = elementListText[i].InnerText;
        elementListText[i].AppendChild(a);
    }
    doc.Save(_SVG_TEXT);
```

In this way I got value twice, one not linked (previous) and one linked (href value), but I am not able to clear text InnerText.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. You are trying to change 3070119100 to 3070119100? They look the same to me.

Comment: No, text have to be replace with a linked text

Comment: Ah, now I see. InnerText is defined like this *Gets or sets the concatenated values of the node and all its child nodes.*, so you cannot change InnerText to a link. You need to add real content.

Comment: I am trying to do but I have always something wrong:  This add an empty text:
                string valore = elementListText[i].InnerText;

                XmlElement a = doc.CreateElement("a");
                a.SetAttribute("xlink:href", "http://www.google.it");
                a.InnerText = valore.Trim();
                elementListText[i].AppendChild(a);

This : is not admitted

                XAttribute attr = new XAttribute("xlink:href", "http://www.google.it");
                XElement innerNode = new XElement("a", attr, valore);
                n.Add(innerNode);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following uses Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string _SVG = @"<text xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" xmlns:xlink=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" xml:space=""preserve"" fill=""#ff0000"" stroke-width=""0"" x=""239.61"" y=""74.89"" font-size=""3.37"" opacity=""1.00"" font-family=""Arial Narrow"">3070119100</text>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(_SVG);

            //to read from file
            //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace xlink = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xlink");

            List<XElement> elementListText = doc.Descendants(ns + "text").ToList();
            foreach(XElement element in elementListText)
            {
                string value = element.Value;
                element.RemoveNodes();

                XElement a = new XElement(ns + "a");
                a.SetAttributeValue(ns + "xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
                a.SetAttributeValue(xlink + "href", "http://www.google.it");
                a.SetValue(value);
                element.Add(a);
            }
            //doc.Save(filename);
        }

    }

}
```